# Count rows in DB where 

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord, codeigniter-2

I'm following a tutorial on Pagination with CI/jQuery. In the tutorial they get the total number of rows by doing:

`$config['total_rows'] = $this->db->count_all('tblUsers');`

They get the total number of users to define the pagination. However, they get ALL users. In my application, I only need the users with a certain value assigned to them, in this case 'role'.

I only need the users where `role = 1` in my DB.

I've tried a couple of things with `->count()` (from CI's Active Record DB class) or trying to `count()` to check how many 'rows' an array has, but I haven't been able to get the result I need. I also tried doing a regular query: `select count(*) from tblusers where role = 1` and then somehow tried grabbing how many it returned, but alas.

Doing

```
$config['total_row'] = $this->db->query("select count(*) from tblusers where role = '1'")->result_array();
```

gives me the following array:

`Array ( [0] => Array ( [count(*)] => 2 ) )`

However, I can't seem to be able to read out the `count(*)` index..

`Message: Undefined index: count(*)`

I hope this makes some sense. Basically I'm trying to do something like..

`$this->db->where('role', 1)->get('tblUsers')->count()`

Sadly, this doesn't work :D

Thanks in advance. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could simply alias the `count(*)` result column:

```
select count(*) as number_of_entries from tblusers where role = '1'
```

You can now use `number_of_entries` as the key from the resulting array to access the needed value.

Comment: Heehee, I feel so stupid now for overlooking that. Always trying to do things the harder way :( Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Not positive, but it seems that all you need is to give that column a name. For example,

```
... = $this->db->query("select count(*) as colname from tblusers where role = '1'")->result_array();
```

I suspect that will work.

Answer (score 2):

For reading the count(*) index use the following to create a readable field:

```
select count(*) as cnt from tblusers where role = 1
```

Now you will have:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [cnt] => 2 ) )
```